# How to retrieve a component from a list, using a variable name in R

Tags: r, list

I have a variable called `temp`, the value of which is always a string, meant to retrieve a component from a list.
The line:

`> list$temp`

does **not** work, since it only retrieves the component called 'temp', not the component with the same name as `temp`'s value.

How do I use `temp`'s value to retrieve a component from the list?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`[[` subsetting](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html) instead of `$` subsetting:

```
list[[temp]]
```